# React error message "map is not a function"

Tags: reactjs, search, mapping, rendering

I created a search engine on my site, so that users can be searched for by their names. Suggestions for user names are supposed to appear based on the letters entered, but as soon as you click on any letter, everything disappears from the screen and an error appears on the console which says:

> map is not a function

*search.jsx* component code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
// import axios from "axios";
import { Button } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import "./search.css";

const Search = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('');
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const onChange = async (e) => {
        setValue(e.target.value)
        const res = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/users')
        const data = await res.json()
        setData(data)
    };

  return (
    <div className="search">
        <div>
            <input
            type="text"
            value={value}
            className="search"
            placeholder="looking for someone?..."
            onChange={onChange}
            />
            <Button>Search</Button>
        </div>
        <div className="dropdown-content">
          {
            data.map((item) => {
            <div key={item.id}>
              {item.name}
            </div>})
          }
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Search
```

The page before searching

[image]

After entering any letter to the search engine

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to see what `const data = await res.json()` returns?

Comment: If `data.map()` is not a function then `data` is not an array.  When you debug, what value does `data` have?  What value did you expect it to have?  Why?

Comment: @David i expect array of users becouse `data` = `res.json()` and `res` = fetching users api

Comment: @PhoenixPhoenix: If the server isn't returning the data you expect then your next step would be to (1) examine what data it *does* return and (2) examine and debug the server-side code which returns that data.

Comment: @David  @Arkellys
this is the console i've did `console.log(data)`  

image link 
https://ibb.co/fx1VStR
all the users are just three users

Comment: @PhoenixPhoenix: And when looking at that output, you observe that `data` is indeed not an array.  It's an object with two properties called `error` and `users`.  Perhaps you want to update state to that `users` property instead?

Comment: @David thanks alot i updated the controller function in the backend and Your comment alerted me to this 
it work now

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77564667/edit). Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the Map function as type Void, but it must return a ReactNode. Refer to the below:

```
data.map((item => 
        <div key={item.id}>
          {item.name}
        </div>)
```